# Error creando excel con datos de una tabla

Tags: java, html5, excel, struts2

Tengo una aplicación java con Struts 2 que estaba funcionando perfectamente y hace poco decidí actualizar las librerías.

He pasado de estas:

```
displaytag-1.2.jar
displaytag-export-poi-1.2.jar
jstl.jar
struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar
```

A estas (Las dos primeras no cambian):

```
displaytag-1.2.jar
displaytag-export-poi-1.2.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
struts2-core-2.5.20.jar
```

A partir del cambio, cada vez que intento exportar los datos de una tabla a excel, me da el siguiente error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.nio.BufferOverflowException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:591)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.apache.struts2.result.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:169)
org.apache.struts2.result.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:206)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:375)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:279)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:250)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:179)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:49)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.doIntercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:142)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:137)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:137)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:201)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:67)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:133)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:89)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:101)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:142)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:160)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:175)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:121)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:167)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:203)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:196)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
es.verifica.admGesco.struts2.AutenticacionInterceptor.intercept(AutenticacionInterceptor.java:84)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:49)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:48)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:574)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:79)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:141)
es.verifica.admGesco.common.displaytag.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:59)
es.verifica.admGesco.struts2.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:35)
```

El código de la tabla es el siguiente:

```
<display-el:table name="informe" uid="tinforme" keepStatus="true" export="true" requestURI="${request['struts.request_uri']}">
    <display-el:column property="id" titleKey="id" media="excel"/>
    <display-el:column property="nombre" titleKey="nombre" media=”excel”/>
    <display-el:column property="numero" titleKey="numero"/>
    <display-el:column property="gastos" titleKey="gastos" format="{0,number,   #,##0.00}"/>
    <display-el:column property="fecha" titleKey="fecha" media="excel"/>
    <display-el:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="informe.xls"/>
</display-el:table>
```

El excel se exporta usando la librería de displaytag.

¿Alguien podría decirme cuál es el problema? ¿Es un problema de configuración, de incompatibilidad entre las nuevas librerías y las librerias de displaytag?

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir la traza de la excepción completa? Y si referencia a parte de tu código la parte relevante que pueda estar afectado por esa excepción.

Comment: He añadido la traza al completo. No hace referencia a nada de mi código, displaytag mediante la etiqueta inferior de la tabla ya llama directamente a su librería de exportación.